# How to determine if property is a nullable reference type?

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I want to know if a property type is a nullable reference type or not. I found several blog posts claiming that we can simply check the custom attributes by reflection. Given the class Foo:

```
public class Foo 
{
    public string Bar1 { get; set; }
    public string? Bar2 { get; set; }
}
```

I make the following calls:

```
typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar1").CustomAttributes //returns an empty collection
typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar2").CustomAttributes //returns a collection with one instance of NullableAttribute
```

Weirdly, when I change the class to:

```
public class Foo 
{
    public string? Bar2 { get; set; }
}
```

Now, the CustomAttributes are empty.

```
typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar2").CustomAttributes //returns an empty collection
```

What is a reliable way to determine if a property type is a nullable reference?

Comment: You could check if it is a `Nullable<T>` and then if the generic argument is a reference type.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen `Nullable<T>` is struct and value type, not the reference one

Comment: The `CustomAttributes` collection should contain a series of elements that all inheirt `System.Attribute`, but those elements should have more specific classes that you can check with `x.GetType()` and I believe there is an overload `GetCustomAttribute<T>()` that lets you get a specific one. There should be a specific attribute that is used for nullable in C#8 although I don't know what it is. If you look for _any_ attribute, you may run into errors with your current method, because attributes are used in many contexts.

Comment: Accroding to [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboGIHtfICQA3kYQPTlqZwAM6AQgIYBOc6x6A5gKYAuAbnQBnfkIC+ZalDoB+RqxgduYkaslJC4oA=) for first case attribute is applied to nullable property, for second one - to `Foo` class itself (because it contains only nullable types, I guess). So, you should check the both cases and can also have a look at [nullable metadata](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/nullable-metadata.md) document. The attached duplicate has an essential answer how to do that properly

Comment: You need to check the entire tree *above* this - the declaring type, module, assembly, etc; it is in/out/in/out

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski It will wrap the original type.  `int?` is actually `Nullable<int>`

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen nullable value types and nullable reference types are different things, first ones is a separate type, `Nullable<T>`, they wrap original type. Nullable reference types added in C# 8and  are implemented using type annotations, they doesn't wrap anything